# strategies and clustering algorithms for topic detection

Tags: cluster-analysis, mahout

i want to know good strategies or algorithms to solve the following problem:

What i have is:
A set of news articles from different sources with a time-stamp and a weighted vector of news categories for each article.

What i want is:
Clusters of articles from different sources that deal with the same topic.

I basically want to copy the key feature of google news: presenting topics and listing different news sources for the same topic.

I already have nice features for the articles like the above mentioned vector of news categories, want i need to do know is chose the right strategy, clustering algorithm and library to do the clustering.

Features the clustering algorithm should have:

1. no fixed number of clusters, (i don't know in advance how many
   topics are present in my article set).
2. efficiently map new articles to existing clusters, or create a new cluster if the
   articles doesn't fit good enough to existing clusters.
3. Take into account the time-stamp of articles for similarity.
4. Dissolve clusters if to get outdated and removed from the underlying article set.

I never did any clustering so I don't know if there is a clustering algorithm that provides the above features or if some of these features are too complicated or make clustering way to slow so that I need to find a workaround for them.

Right know I'm looking at mahout as a library for clustering. Are there any ready to use open source implementations for Topic detection with mahout or maybe with another library?

Comment: How big is your dataset ? Mahout is datamining and machine learning on Hadoop, which should be great for big data but probably overkill in other cases. If you're new to datamining and like python, take a look at scikit learn, which has a nice documentation http://scikit-learn.org/stable/

Answer (score 0):

I think the following paper is one of the best approaches I have yet encountered for topic detection when you do not know the number of clusters already.

http://www.uni-weimar.de/medien/webis/research/events/tir-08/tir08-papers-final/wartena08-topic-detection-by-clustering-keywords.pdf

Comment: Page, which above link directs, seems to be removed.